Coordinate transformations of a scalar field
I'm very confused about coordinate transformations and the statement that scalar fields remain unchanged under coordinate transformations.
Consider a coordinate transformation $$ x \rightarrow x'  $$
We want to know how the fields change under this transformation. Is it true that we just put in the change in the coordinates in the argument of the field? So that:
$$ \phi (x) \rightarrow \phi(x')$$
But if $ \phi(x) $ is supposed to be a scalar field, the field value at the same point p in space should remain the same independent of the coordinates we use. But when we went from the x coordinates to the x' coordinates, the numbers we put into $ \phi$ differs and we will get different values from the function $ \phi$. But we want those values to be the same, since it is a scalar field, that should have the same field value regardless of the coordinates we are using.
They often state that a scalar field is such that
$$ \phi'(x') = \phi(x) $$
But what does $ \phi' $ mean? When we just change the coordinates we only change the argument from x to x'. We do not change the structure of the field right?
Can someone help me clarify this.

It may be helpful to learn about the distinction between "active transformations" and "passive transformations," which is physics terminology but is a meaningful distinction in math too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation

The transformation means concretely that $x'$ is a function of $x$, i.e. $x' = f(x)$, which implies $\phi(x) = \phi(f^{-1}(x')) = \phi'(x')$, where $\phi' = \phi \circ f^{-1}$. What is the purpose of this new map $\phi'$ ?
Since $\phi$ is a scalar field, it depends on a vectorial quantity $x$, while being itself scalar. In consequence, after a transformation acting on $x$, the latter has to be "compensated", because a scalar should be invariant under such a transformation.
In order to do so, a new map $\phi'$ has to be defined with respect to $x'$, in such a way that the quantity $\phi(x) = \phi'(x')$ is conserved. At this stage, it is important to distinguish the map $\phi$ as a function from the scalar $\phi(x)$ as an image of this map, which may be confusing indeed.
Think of $\phi(x)$ as a mass distribution as a simple concrete example. If you want to switch to the spherical coordinates $x' = f(x)$ for instance, only your way to "measure" space has changed, but not the real distribution of physical bodies, that is why the transformation on $x$ must be compensated in order to keep the same mass distribution at the end.

yeah ok. But should it not be $\phi(x) = \phi(f^{-1}(x'))$ ?

@bennnn   Sorry, I wrote this answer in a hurry, this was an error of mine, now corrected. Moreover, I've edited my answer in order to clarify its interpretation, as well as to give a concrete example.
